# Can two EC2 instances have the same $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']? Or how to uniquely identify each, in EC2?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I need a unique identifier for each EC2 instance of my scaling group on AWS for a prefix for `uniqid()`.

Can I use `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code can fetch the instance id of your ec2 instance:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$instance_id = file_get_contents("http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/instance-id");
echo $instance_id;
?>
```

Comment: I thought about metadata but isn't this rate limited?

Comment: "We throttle queries to the instance metadata service on a per-instance basis, and we place limits on the number of simultaneous connections from an instance to the instance metadata service." So can I somehow write the id on instance startup to a php file that I implement in my script?

Comment: I'm really new to this amazon services but here's my suggestion. How about create a datafile or database, and add this id to it, if it isn't already added? And then fetch it from the data source whenever required?

Comment: Using a database would be a bit tricky -  how would you check if a unique identifier has been written to it when you don't know the unique identifier? But I also came up with the local file solution. Try to include server_id.php, when it doesn't exist fetch the server id and create server_id.php with the id. I think this would do the job.

Answer (score 2):

The instance ID from the ec2 metadata is a good answer, but stashing its value in the environment seems like a cleaner solution.

Wherever you set environment variables in your setup -- in the startup script for the web server itself (one example, not universally applicable, would be `/etc/init.d/apache2`), fetch the value and store it in the environment.

```sh
export EC2_INSTANCE_ID=$(ec2metadata --instance-id)
```

`$_ENV["EC2_INSTANCE_ID"]` should then contain the value, much less tedious than caching it in a file, and not subject to rate limiting (which is documented as being imposed, but without specific thresholds being mentioned).

---

Note that the following three examples for fetching the instance ID are functionally equivalent:

```sh
ec2metadata --instance-id
curl http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/instance-id
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id
```

Comment: I really like this solution. I have never used environmental variables but it I will definitely try this.

Comment: You might find this useful, then, if you haven't already found it by now: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php.  (PHP isn't my specialty, so I had to look it up myself).  Apparently there's also `getenv()`.

Comment: I tried to use environment variables but it seems that it is not possible, see my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41331993/retrieving-an-environment-variable-in-php/41332070#41332070

Comment: Huge bummer if true, but difficult to believe.  There may, at least, be a way to tell Apache to pass it through.  I'll have to dust off some PHP and see what I can find.

Comment: Maybe [`PassEnv`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_env.html#passenv)?

Comment: Something I do not like when using environment variables is that they are gone when the server restarts. So don't you think using php file handling would be much easier?

Comment: They aren't gone if their values are set during the process of restarting the server (automatically, during the startup script).  I'm not saying it's The One True Way™ but, done correctly, it's clean and should "just work."